# Jenkins library: How to use one library in another one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two different libraries, a common one CommonLib and a project specific one ProjectLib. They are loaded dynamically in the Jenkinsfile as follows.

```groovy
library identifier: 'CommonLib@master', retriever: modernSCM(
[$class: 'GitSCMSource',
     remote: 'https://bitbucket.intra/scm/common/pipeline-helper.git',
     credentialsId: 'bitbucket.user'
])
library identifier: 'ProjectLib@master', retriever: modernSCM(
[$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: 'https://bitbucket.intra/scm/project/jenkins-pipeline-helper-project.git',
   credentialsId: 'bitbucket.user'
 ])
```

Now in the vars (`vars\test.groovy`) of the `ProjectLib`, I have a function which shall call a function from the `commonLib` (`vars\runPowershellResScript.groovy`). My try is as follows:

```groovy
def call() {
    library 'CommonLib'
    runPowershellResScript('ch/mycompany/common/scripts/test.ps1', "-homeDir 'd:\\projectxy")
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work as I expect and this error.

```
No library named CommonLib found
```

How can I use a dynamically loaded library within another?